# Type of a data chunk in Node http request

Tags: node.js

I am studying code [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/) of setting up a simple Node server. I have seen and used many times this idiom of saving data chunks in an array and finally concatenating them together.

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var body = [];
  request.on('data', function(chunk) { body.push(chunk); });
  request.on('end', function() { body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
  ...
```

1. **What is the type of `chunk`?** [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) says it's either`Buffer` or `string`, but which one?
2. **Is it safe to call `Buffer.concat(body)` where `body` is an array of strings?**  [Documentation of `Buffer.concat(list)`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) says `list` should be a list of Buffer instances. Are strings "Buffer instances"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same documentation also states:

> The listener callback will be passed the chunk of data as a string if a default encoding has been specified for the stream using the `readable.setEncoding()` method; otherwise the data will be passed as a `Buffer`.

Because your code isn't calling `setEncoding`, `chunk` will be a Buffer.

> Is it safe to call `Buffer.concat(body)` where `body` is an array of strings?

```
> Buffer.concat(['foo', 'bar', 'xxx'])
TypeError: "list" argument must be an Array of Buffers
```

So no. But since `body` will be an array of Buffer, `Buffer.concat(body)` should work just fine.